# GNU sed - sustain leading spaces

Tags: regex, bash, sed, gnu

I am trying to convert a database type to another one. It is not just a simple substitution but I want to extend columns length by a specific factor. For example:

```
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(50) ----> VARCHAR(60)
```

This can be achieved with the bellow sed command however it does not preserve the leading spaces. I suspect that the problem is in the ending flag /ge which is needed for the evaluation of the calculation.

```
sed -r  's/(^.*)NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING\(([0-9]+)\)/ echo \1 VARCHAR"("$(echo "scale=0;\2*1.2\/1"\|bc)")"/ge'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the backreference while `echo`ing.  Say:

```
sed -r 's/(^.*)NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING\(([0-9]+)\)/ echo "\1"VARCHAR"("$(echo "scale=0;\2*1.2\/1"\|bc)")"/ge' filename
```